# Arranging numbers along lines

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, even-and-odd-functions

I have to arrange the numbers $1,\ 2,\ ...,\ 9$ on the points in the lines such that every two lines the sum of their elements is equal.

[image]

My Solution:

We already know that $1 +  2 + ... + 9 = 45$

Let $x_1,\ x_2$ and $x_3$ the numbers in the fist line (from Top-Down)

$x_3,\ x_4$ and $x_5$ the numbers in the second line

$x_5,\ x_6$ and $x_7$ the numbers in the third line

and $x_7,\ x_8$ and $x_9$ the numbers in the fourth line

Then $$45 + x_3 + x_5 + x_7 = 4k$$

The smallest multiple of $4$ this is grether than 45 is $48$ That mean $$x_3 + x_5 + x_7 = 3$$ well the equation is unsolveable for 3. Let go head to the next multiple of 4 that is 52 that means $$x_3 + x_5 + x_7 = 7$$
The equation is solveablefor $$x_3 = 1 \text{ and } x_5 = 4 \text{ and } x_7 = 2$$
We can immediately $x_4$ because $x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 13$ Hence $x_4 = 13 - 7 = 6$

Further $x_1 = 3,\ x_2=9,\ x_3=1,\ x_4=8,\ x_5=4,\ x_6=7,\ x_7=2,\ x_8=6\text{ and } x_9=5$

Considerung the solution is came across an other solution. Well my question is there a way to cover the solution space.

Comment: Brute force suggests to me that $96$ of the $9!=362880$ possible permutations will satisfy your conditions, though this amounts to $12$ sets of eight solutions which are essentially the same when you consider $x_1,x_2,x_8,x_9$ and the whole order.   For example, a solution with $x_3 + x_5 + x_7 = 7$ is $3, 9, 1, 8, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6$ but you could swap the first and second terms, or eighth and ninth terms, or reverse the whole sequence, and still have such a solution.